# Call sql server function from oracle and get result value

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, odbc, procedure

Via an ODBC database link from Oracle (11g) to MS-SQL Server (2012) we try to call a function/procedure that returns an integer.
The SQL-Server-procedure is named spProcTest2 with 2 parameters. This procedure returns an integer that is used as an error-code.
For an example of the code, see below.

The question is how to receive the value that is returned by the procedure?

NOTE: The value 'nr' that is used in the code below only returns the number of affected rows.

```
declare
    c        INTEGER;
    nr       INTEGER;
    v_sql    VARCHAR2(1000);
    SOUT     VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_sql :='EXEC dbo.spProcTest2 ?, ?;';

    c  := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@gtlab;

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@gtlab(c, v_sql );

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@gtlab (c,  1 , 1);
    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@gtlab (c,  2 , 5);

    nr := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@gtlab(c);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nr=' || nr) ;    

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@gtlab(c);

    commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v_sql :='declare @resxml xml exec dbo.TestProcedure 2, @resxml output select cast(@resxml as varchar(8000)) as vres';
```

1. declare @resxml xml
2. exec dbo.TestProcedure 2, @resxml output
3. select cast(@resxml as varchar(8000)) as vres (Convert XML to VARCHAR)

All proc

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLSQLPROC(
v_out out varchar2, 
v_res out integer)
IS
  c             INTEGER;
  v_sql         VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN

    v_sql :='declare @resxml xml exec dbo.TestProcedure 2, @resxml output select cast(@resxml as varchar(8000)) as vres';

    c  := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@NSK_LIFE;

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@NSK_LIFE(c, v_sql );

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@NSK_LIFE(c,1, v_out);

    v_res := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.FETCH_ROW@NSK_LIFE(c);

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@NSK_LIFE(c,1,v_out); 

    DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@NSK_LIFE(c);
END;
```